# How to rename a file in Azure File Share using Azure Python SDK?

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-file-share

I am trying to rename a file in Azure File Share using the Azure python SDK. But the problem I'm facing is, it removes the file instead of renaming it.

```
with directory_client.get_file_client(file_name=project_from_db.project_name) as rename_client:
    rename_client.rename_file(new_name=new_data['project_name'])
```

Is anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, In my environment, I have the file name with **`sprite.html`** in Azure File share.

**Portal:**
[image]

You can use the below code to rename a file in Azure File Share using Azure Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareServiceClient


# Define the connection string and file share name
connection_string = "your-connection string"
file_share_name = "fileshare2"    
        
file_name="sprite.html"
new_file_name="sprite326.html"

share_service_client = ShareServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
share_client = share_service_client.get_share_client(file_share_name)
file_client = share_client.get_file_client(file_name)

new_file_client=share_client.get_file_client(new_file_name) 
new_file_client.start_copy_from_url(file_client.url)

file_client.delete_file()
print("The file is Renamed successfully:",{new_file_name})
```

**Output:**

```
The file is Renamed successfully: {'sprite326.html'}
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure Storage File Share client library for Python | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-file-share-readme?view=azure-python)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the same code below, by just adding the path of the old file with the new name of the file, to the new_path parameter .

```
new_file_path = <file-path> + new_data['project_name']
with directory_client.get_file_client(file_name=project_from_db.project_name) as rename_client:
    rename_client.rename_file(new_name = new_file_path)
```

By doing the above change, the file will be renamed in the same path as the old file was.

Hope it helps other people out there facing the same issue!